# How to protect API routes in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am using Next.js API routes - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction but I don't know how to protect them from public.

Now those routes are public in my production server.

For example: when I go to `mysite.com/api/cats` in browser, it returns -

```json
{ success: true, data: [...] }
```

Please help, how do I hide those API routes from public?

Comment: Define "public". Are you trying to stop people using your app from accessing the API? How is the app supposed to access the API then?

Comment: My app has only one page (index), `/` and it doesn't use authentication. For example when you go to `mysite.com/api/cats` in browser, you will see the raw json data. I just want to prevent that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prevent the browser from requesting the URL then the user won't see the data when they type the URL into the address bar **and** your JavaScript won't see it when it makes an Ajax request to the same URL.

You can't hide the data from the user of the browser while still allowing your application running in the same browser to access it.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will just have to use the same old API key.

Comment: What about a necessary "key=" param where a value only the developer knows is set when calling the api via ajax or whatever it is backend? Something as google does for its APIs.. wouldn't that hide the route to users if manually typed (because it would need the key param) but allow the backend api calls at the sane time?

Comment: @m4tt — If you need to pass a key in the URL when you make the request and the request has to come from the browser, then you have to give the key to the browser where the user can access it. If you want the request to come from the server and not the browser then you're looking at the wrong question.

Answer (score 2):

**1.Use Authentication :**

```js
export default async function apiRouteName(req, res) {
  //way of getting the token totally depends on your preference
  let token = req.cookies.jwtToken || req.headers.jwtToken || req.query.jwtToken
  
  if(!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({message:"you are not allowed"});
  }
  
  let data = {}; //store your data in  this variable
  return res.status(200).json({data})
  
}
```

**2.Middleware :**

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function  middleware (req  ,  event ) {
   //way of getting the token totally depends on your preference
   let token = req.cookies.jwtToken || req.headers.jwtToken
   if (!token ) {
     return NextResponse.redirect('/login');
   }
   
    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Comment: first method is pretty simple for me . But how middle works with api ? I mean if someone use api in postman how middware will work ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you want to know how to secure the endpoints so that you can only access them with a token right?

If so, a quick and easy way is to use Next-Auth along with the getSession hook.

```
    import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
          
    export default async function handler(
            req: NextApiRequest,
            res: NextApiResponse<Data>
        ) {
            const session = await getSession({ req });

            if (!session)
                return res.status(401).send({
                    message: 'Unauthenticated user. Your IP has been logged',
                });
            //handle the request here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using getSession()#
You can protect API routes using the getSession() method.

Using getToken()#
If you are using JSON Web Tokens you can use the getToken() helper to access the contents of the JWT without having to handle JWT decryption / verification yourself. This method can only be used server side.

See here : [https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#:~:text=You%20can%20protect%20API%20routes%20using%20the%20getSession()%20method](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#:%7E:text=You%20can%20protect%20API%20routes%20using%20the%20getSession()%20method).